# My app is throwing a random undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently creating a job board and in my listings/new.html.erb file and I have a section within the form for people to choose a category. The category is its own separate model.

But when I submit the form I get a 'undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass' error.

Below are my models, controllers, and the part of the view which is appropriate. Thank you ahead of time.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
<h4>Job Category:</h4>
  <%= form.select(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories)) %>
</div>
```

**listings_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
end

def create
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
@listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
@listing.category_id = params[:category_id]
charge_error = nil

if @listing.valid?
  begin
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => 'example@stripe.com',
      :card => params[:stripeToken])

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => 150,
        :description => 'Job Posting via Remote Business Jobs',
        :currency => 'usd')

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    charge_error = e.message
  end
  if charge_error
    flash[:error] = charge_error
    render :new
  else
    @listing.save
    redirect_to @listing
  end
else
  flash[:error] = 'one or more errors in your orders'
  render :new
end
end
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :body, :apply_link, 
  :company_link, :employment_type, :company, :salary_range, 
  :category_id, 
 :slug, :hq)
end
```

**listing.rb**

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

 belongs_to :category
```

end

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

 has_many :listings
end
```

**Edit Log**:
I updated the **listings_controller.rb** to include

```
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
```

Comment: What line is the error thrown from?

Comment: It's being thrown at the line which shows `<%= form.select(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories)) %>`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing this line from your `create` action, just make sure it's before any `render :new`. This is needed because you're using this in the form in case something fails.

```
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the `@categories` variable isn't used in the create action, or am I missing it?

Comment: Disregard my comment. The line should be before the `render :new` in create method, in case it fails, the view tries to use `@categories`, and the options_for_select is the one throwing the error, as it tries to map <option>-elements.

Comment: The I be replacing anything in my `create` action for `@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }`?

Comment: No, just add it at the top of the `create` action, that's the safest way. It will not be executed until the form is displayed, so don't worry about any performance hit.

Comment: Alright, It may have worked but I'm getting a new error which is `category must exist`. I checked my console and the category record does in face exist.